# React Hot Loader Sporadic Updates on Windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hot-loader

`react-hot-loader` will not update on file save (most of the time) on windows 7.  Tried the very same code on my Mac and it works every time.

Searched for potential problems, but came up empty.

Does windows have a quirk when performing OS level notification of file changes?

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS, but it looks like the hot reloader cannot communicate with the browser, maybe due to some network reason like the IP :( or windows could not match with the IP 0.0.0.0 of the hot reload socket?

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo I have the terminal open which always updates before the browser, so I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: May be also Windows doesn't resolve the path the same as Mac OS/Linux system, the paths you give on your webpack file

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo It works sometimes, but not most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue on Windows. I wasn't able to find the source of the problem or completely resolve the issue, but I do have some suggestions for you.

1. Add newlines at the bottom of your file and save again. This will often trigger a hot reload where saving other changes to your code won't. (Then delete the newlines right away so you don't forget to later).
2. Use a Linux virtual machine for React development on a Windows PC.